# How to integrate AWS Lex chatbot in Xamarin application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin

I have basic understanding of .net and chatbot. 
I wanted to integrate Amazon lex in xamarin(ios, android)app. There seems to be no example or sample. I have created chatbot from AWS platform intent and slots.

Also I wanted to use database to get query return. Any sample to integrate AWS Lex with Xamarin app would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe this would help you out https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/bots-just-got-better-net-toolkit-lex-lambda-cognito/

Comment: no thats for web. i saw there is awssdk.lex  but threre no sample i could find as to how i can integrate Lex in xamarin app.  AWS says iOS , android and react native can be used to integrate.  but  if i can add awssdk.lex in to xamarin why not single example how to add Lex...

Comment: Because any .Net code is expected to work i guess...

Comment: Have you tried using the instructions linked, but implement the code in the C# portion of a Xamarin app?  Does it work, not work, if so what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no direct solution like Amazon Lex is supported by React-native. i confirmed with xamarin team as well as AWS service one of the member. direct integration not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question, you already have some implementation of chatbot made with AWS services, but you are having issue on integrating it to your xamarin application to be able to use it in IOS and Android devices.

For that purpose, there is AWS Mobile SDK which happens to support also xamarin.

From their link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/Welcome.html

I also did not find a Lex tutorial directly, but a very promising quote:

> Supported AWS services currently include, but are not limited to [narrow list of services]

was on the same page. I looked around, found this text:

> The AWS Mobile SDK for .NET and Xamarin also allows you to use most of the AWS services supported by the AWS SDK for .NET. The AWS services specific to mobile development are explained in this developer guide. For more information about the AWS SDK for .NET, see [a link]

clicked the link and ended here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html

and under link AmazonLex -> AmazonLexClient there was something, you probably wanted to see:

> Version Information
>   .NET Standard:
>   Supported in: 1.3
>   .NET Framework:
>   Supported in: 4.5, 4.0, 3.5
>   Portable Class Library:
>   Supported in: Windows Store Apps
>   Supported in: Windows Phone 8.1
>   Supported in: Xamarin Android
>   Supported in: Xamarin iOS (Unified)
>   Supported in: Xamarin.Forms

Those 3 last let me understand that whenever you setup Mobile SDK, you get access to AWS services in Xamarin, also Lex.

Steps to install on

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/setup.html

mainly contain steps on how to create xamarin app and get AWS account, most important is to install the AWS Mobile SDK for .NET and Xamarin and configure it. More detailed steps are under that link.

After that the process is to follow the instructions on:

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/bots-just-got-better-net-toolkit-lex-lambda-cognito/module-one/

like pointed in comments. I suppose once you have access to any service via Mobile SDK, the wire up of Lex may go in similar steps and no special just xamarin tutorial is not needed anymore.

Comment: hello,  i have created chatbot using my amazon account (online).  https://aws.amazon.com/lex/?nc=sn&loc=2&dn=4                        created cognito /role attaché policies n all.

Comment: now i want to integrate created chatbot in xamarin mobile app. there is an example to integrate lex in Swift / android Java / react native.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/mobile-hub-getting-started.html    (add conventional bot at the bottom of page) these examples for SWIFT / ANDROID (java /kotlin) but there is nothing for xamarin mobile app.   one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/setup.html mention only 7 services available for xamarin to be integrated which does not include Lex

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for both architecture and sample code for implementing AWS Lex bot with .NET backend that can be integrated with iOS/Android Frontend.

You have multiple choices here to do it

1. Build both chat user interfaces in iOS and Android and integrate them AWS iOS & Android SDKs to utilize the AWS LEX bot.
2. Just implement a bot user interface in iOS and Android app and integrate it with a .NET backend that can utilize AWS .NET SDK to integrate with your LEX bot.

I would recommend the second approach as it will save you writing the LEX integration code twice both in Android and in iOS. In the second appraoch you will be able to write a single integration for AWS LEX in .NET and that can give a unified experience across the mobile devices(iOS/Android)

Now for the .NET based backend integration with AWS LEX bot.

If you are an experienced .NET developer and you know how will you host your code then only thing that you need is the .NET API reference for AWS LEX, which can be found here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Lex/TLexClient.html

But if you are not sure how to write this integration code and also not sure how the deployment will look like then you can follow the below tutorial

[Bots Just Got Better with .NET and the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/bots-just-got-better-net-toolkit-lex-lambda-cognito/)

Also, find here the architecture form the above tutorial

[image]

Comment: hello, i have created chatbot using my amazon account (online). aws.amazon.com/lex/?nc=sn&loc=2&dn=4 created cognito /role attaché policies n all.

Comment: now i want to integrate created chatbot in xamarin mobile app. there is an example to integrate lex in Swift / android Java / react native. docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/… (add conventional bot at the bottom of page) these examples for SWIFT / ANDROID (java /kotlin) but there is nothing for xamarin mobile app. one docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/… mention only 7 services available for xamarin to be integrated which does not include Lex

Comment: like above example i did not found anything for xamarin app.....also i enquired with xamarin forum i got response as of now Amazon Lex can not be integrated in to xamarin mobile app....